# Proof of the Extension theorem of sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I just go through the proof of the extension theorem in the book of Evan - Partial differential equations (First edition, section 5.4, pages 254-257).

I was thinking about point 4 of the proof, that is

> 4. Using these calculations we readily check as well
>      $$\|\bar{u}\|_{W^{1 , p}(B)} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1, p}\left(B^{+}\right)}$$
>      for some constant $C$ which does not depend on $u$..

Here, $\bar u$ is the higher order reflection of $u$ from $B^+ := B\cap \{x_n>0\}$ to $B^- := B\cap \{ x_n < 0 \}$ for some ball $B$, given by
$$
\bar{u}(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
u(x) & \text { if } x \in B^{+} \\
-3 u\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1},-x_{n}\right)+4 u\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1},-\frac{x_{n}}{2}\right) & \text { if } x \in B^{-}
\end{array}\right.
$$

this inequality should follow from the calculations before. But it looks like that it isn't that simple or at least it isn't that simple for me.

Could you help me with this inequality. Thank you!

Edit: If I have the inequality $\int_{B^-} |D^{\alpha} \bar{u} |^p  \leq C \int_{B^+} |D^{\alpha}   u  |^p$, then I see how the upper inequality follows.

For $B^+$ I should get: $\int_{B^+} |D^{\alpha} \bar{u} |^p  = \int_{B^+} |D^{\alpha}   u  |^p$

and

for $B^-$: $\int_{B^-} |D^{\alpha} \bar{u} |^p = \int_{B^-} |D^{\alpha} (-3u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, -x_n) + 4u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, - \frac{x_n}{2})) |^p \\
= \int_{B^-} |-3D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, -x_n) + 4D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, - \frac{x_n}{2}) |^p $

so here there have to exists a constant c_1 such that

$\int_{B^-} |-3D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, -x_n) + 4D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, - \frac{x_n}{2}) |^p \\ \leq  c_1 \int_{B^-} |-D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, -x_n) + D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, - \frac{x_n}{2}) |^p$

If I now get the estimation 
$c_1 \int_{B^-} |-D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, -x_n) + D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, - \frac{x_n}{2}) |^p \\ \leq  c_2 \int_{B^-} |-D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, -x_n)|^p + |D^{\alpha} u(x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, - \frac{x_n}{2}) |^p$

I could maybe use a transformation to get to $B^+$? But it dosn't look that trivial for me or is that your trivial way how to get to the inequality?

Comment: Can you please provide us more content for this formula, for the people who don't have this book?

Comment: yes you’re just one step away from the answer, use the obvious map from $B^-$ to $B^+$ which flips the $x_n$ coordinate. The 1/2 can only help because you’re just integrating on a subset of the half ball. you pick up a multiplicative constant which is allowed

Comment: Do you get it? Hopefully that was clear

Comment: Yes I think so. I will have a closer look today or tomorrow. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of $\bar u$, its trivial that for any multiindex $\alpha$, $0\le |\alpha|\le 1$,
$$ \int_{B^{\pm}} |D^\alpha\bar u|^p \le C \int_{B^+} |D^\alpha u|^p .$$
The point of the calculations leading to this claim is to check that $D^\alpha\bar u$ is actually defined on $B$, i.e. that $\bar u$ is differentiable  on $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I don't get it why this inequality is trivia. Could you be more precisely?

Comment: @Matzi (1) expand $D^\alpha \bar u$ for $B^+$ using the definition of $\bar u$.  (2) do the same thing for $B^-$. After you do this tell me if you're stuck, and then I can help you from there

Comment: May I ask for you help again. I edited my post and hope I did what you told me